# push new variable values to form serialization

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a login form in which Username and password is set. On lciking of login button javascript function is being called, where I'm making an ajax request to login controller. Form is serialized using following code

```
var parameters = this.login_form.serialize(true);
```

I want to push one new variable the form and tried

```
var parameters = this.login_form.serializeArray(true);
parameters.push({ name: "mysql", value: "update" }); 
// remaining code to make ajax request
```

which throws error shown below.

> TypeError: this.login_form.serializeArray is not a function

How can I push new variable values?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Where does login_form come from? What is it? And please, try to make more clear what you mean.

Comment: can you add hidden field in html "mysql" and set its value to "update" and then serialize the form

Comment: Can't you `eval('('+parameters+')')` to add your extra parameters on the object form and then re-serialize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serializeArray()` is a jQuery method, but `this.login_form` is a DOM element. You need to call `jQuery` to convert it:

```
var parameters = $(this.login_form).serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**go with this **
var parameters = $("form").serializeArray();
parameters.push({ name: "mysql", value: "update" });
```

Comment: Answers on SO should be more complete than this. At the very least you should point out the specific problem, what was done to resolve it, and why.